# Are there known issues about UPPER, LOWER SQL functions in ArcGIS 10, file GDB?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, .net, file-geodatabase

Platform: ArcGIS 10 SP3, .NET

I use:
IQueryFilter queryFilter = new QueryFilterClass();
with ArcGIS .NET SDK and build a query...

**Does anybody had problems using UPPER(stringField) and LOWER(stringField) functions on esri file geodatabases?** If so, please share links to some "confirmed-will-fix-in-2-years" pages...

I know we have some "old" warnings in our codebase about that. Like we though UPPER(stringField1)=UPPER(stringField2) doesn't work on file gdb. Last week I ran into it again but it seems I could not get even UPPER(stringField)=('STRING-IN-mixedCACE'.toUpper()) query to find anything in gdb.
UPPER(stringField)='STRING-IN-UPPERCACE' works, but the UPPER should be better named NOOP.

Example. There is a record in fgdb where stringField='Abc'. The query UPPER(stringField)='ABC' returns 0 records. (Error: Should be 1!)

PS. Such UPPER/LOWER queries seem to work correctly in ArcMap when using feature layer definition query.

Example 2.

```
Table (id, stringField)
1, 'Abc'
2, 'ABC'

QueryFilter: where UPPER(stringField)='ABC'
returns: (2, 'ABC')
should-return: (1, 'Abc'), (2, 'ABC')
```

Comment: Perhaps I am misunderstanding your question, but I am not sure what results you expect.. `UPPER(stringField)='mixedCASE'` will never match anything. `UPPER(stringField='ABC')` will never match anything as well. `UPPER(stringField)='ABC'` is the correct expression.

Comment: Thats for you attention, you are correct. Did some edits.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the following SQL sytax with iQueryFilter.WhereClause?

```
Query: select * where UPPER(stringField)='ABC'
```

Omit `Select * Where` from the expression. The syntax for IQueryFilter.WhereClause is `UPPER("LAST_NAME") = 'JONES'`

Also, to query FGDB (as well as D-Base table, Coverage Info table or Shapefile) you must enclose the **field name in double quotes**.

[More here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/vba_desktop/componenthelp/index.html#/WhereClause_Property/001w000006n5000000/)

Comment: No, I'm not using 'select *', updated a question... Thanks for your double-quoting suggestion, will check later.

Comment: I stopped at a breakpoint and used that nice Visual Studio feature immediate window or so. (I tried to q-search for an exact name but it looks other guys like other features so that name may be not exactly correct.) It looks quoted names (LAST_NAME -> "LAST_NAME") do not work either.

Comment: Then I tried to write a 'failing unit test', but (probably) found there are some issues with setting up licenses in MTA. q-searched... Hrr. There are too way many "powerpoint programmers" in esri... (btw, did you notice that lowercase?!) So this may take some time.